# css text wrap with floated image in a jquery mobile view

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, breadcrumbs

I am developing a jquery mobile view and have a problem with breadcrumb text position and word wrap, positioned to the bottom left of an linked image that has been floated to the right of the containing div.

```
  <div data-role="content" class="breadcrumb">
         @Html.Loop(@Content.Traverse.AncestorsBetween(0, 10), @<span>@Html.Link(item.Data).Class(item.Data == Content.Current.Item ? "lef " : "crumb")</span>, separator:@<span class="separator"> / </span>)
         @DisplayBread(@Model.parentpage.ID)
         <a href="tel:0000001000" data-role="button" data-shadow="false" data-theme="none" id="cnow"><img src="~/Dinamico/Themes/Default/Content/image-const/call-us.png" border="0" /></a>
     </div>
```

I should note that the above script contains escaped .net mvc c# code  - (@) 
All this code does is return a breadcrumb link, with anchor tag attributes assigned the name 'lef'.

So essentially I have a containing div class named 'breadcrumb'. Within this containing element is the breadcrumb that has a class named left and an anchored image - the anchor tag has an id named 'cnow'.

The css -

```
.breadcrumb {
    padding: 2px 0px 0px 15px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #e2e2ef;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 2px;
    border-top-color: #3f0f6f;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: #3f0f6f;
    font-size: 12.8px;
    line-height: 19.2px;
}

.lef {
   position:relative;
word-wrap:break-word;
}

#cnow {
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
    clear: both;
}
```

This screenshot shows the current situation - https://www.mediafire.com/?j5me73242ne9585

What I need the css to do is to position the breadcrumb text to the bottom left hand of the image. When the breadcrumb grows (text lengthens), I want it wrap around the image so that the last line of text is at the foot of the image. See my second image - http://www.mediafire.com/view/zbw72l6sdoj5pqa/screen2.png.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might fit what you would like to accomplish, but it adds a table layer to the html:

http://jsfiddle.net/MN4mq/

```
<div data-role="content" class="breadcrumb">
    <table class="lef">
        <td style="vertical-align:bottom;"> 
         Text Text More Text on and ondjflasdjfljsdfljdsl asjfls fjsd sdajsa sdajl safdlj sfladsf lsad asdlsdaj lsadlj afdlj
            </td>
        <td style="vertical-align:bottom;"> <a href="tel:0000001000" data-role="button" data-shadow="false" data-theme="none" id="cnow"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/google/chrome/96/Google-Chrome-icon.png" border="0" /></a>
        </td>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Despite the fact that I don't like having to use tables for front end layout, the solution you offer works for all my Jquery mobile breadcrumb views, and because of the fact that no one else has proffered an alternative, I will credit you for providing the correct answer - Thanks.